# Bintray synchronization with Maven Central

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to sync my library with Maven Central, but I get this error:

[image]
[image]

What should I do? Please give step by step instructions . I know that you want to create files and pom.xml setting.xml , but shde create them and what plainy need to connect ?

Comment: You should offer an signature file and of course javadoc file as the error message states...

Comment: I'm sorry , but I do not understand what you mean . Can you tell me more?

Comment: You need to sign your files via GPG cause that's a requirement for files to be get into Maven Central. Also it is needed having a `-javadoc` file as well...

Comment: Can you give me a link to instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package should be complaint with all the [Maven Central requirements](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html), while in your case your packages aren't signed and (as the bottom of the screenshot shows) have POM files that don't meet the requirements. While Bintray can't help you with your POM files, it can [sign the files you upload for you](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_gpgsigning.html).

If you have specific questions about other failures (after you figured out the signing), feel free to post additional questions with the failure log.

Comment: Most likely you have updated the interface of the site and I can not find a checkbox GPG sign uploaded files automatically http://prntscr.com/af5t1o. What should I do?

Comment: Did you set the keypair in your (or your org's) profile?

Comment: Now the two checkboxes should appear on the repo settings page.

Comment: Ok, I've got my package https://bintray.com/imangazaliev/maven/quickmenu library . Why do I need a repository , and how to properly set up ? http://prntscr.com/afih0x

Comment: Oops, sorry , I found

Comment: I get this error http://prntscr.com/afiqkf . What should I write in gradle, to generate javadoc?

Comment: that's a whole different question that has been asked and answered on SO tons of times. BTW, I think you forgot to accept and vote for the right answer to your original question.